# Problema en la comunicación de un serviceWorker

Tags: javascript, service-workers

estoy teniendo el siguiente problema:

Al enviar un dato al serviceWorker desde el index.js no consigo que este ultimo(serviceWorker) me responda o muestre el dato que le envié por consola.

Esto es lo que tengo en el index:

```
    if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register("./serviceworkers/chat.js")

    sendBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let text = 'My message'
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((res) => res.active.postMessage(text))
        console.log('Send')
    })
    navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
        console.log(e.data)
    })
}
```

Y esto es lo que tengo en el serviceWorker:

```
self.addEventListener('install', () =>{
console.log('Instalado')
})
self.addEventListener('activate', () =>{
    console.log('activado')
})
self.addEventListener('message', (e) =>{
    console.log("message ", e.data)
    e.source.postMessage(e.data)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambie de lugar el seviceWorker. Lo moví al mismo directorio que el index y ya funciona.

Este es el cambio que hice:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register("chat.js")
```